# Setting x-axis breaks to the negative of the x aesthetics

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to make a plot where the breaks along the x-axis are the negative of the actual values I plot. Something like this

```
df <- tibble(x = seq(-1000, 0, length.out = 100),
         y = 2 * x + 3)
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = df$x, labels = -df$x)
```

except that this puts a break at every x value and I would like the breaks to be what I would get using `waiver()`. I recall seeing a solution for this, but for the life of me I cannot remember what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = pretty(df$x), labels = -pretty(df$x))
```

`pretty` is all you need.

Alternatively, just plot directly and use a reversed scale:

```
ggplot(df) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = -x, y = y)) +
  scale_x_reverse()
```